Excel-VBA, replacing cell references within a formula with their values, without evaluating formula fully
e.g.
A1=1, B1=2
C1=A1*B1

I want to replace C1 to be C1=1*2, but not to fully evaluate C1 so that C1=2, that it keeps the structure of the formulae.
My sheet has a number of excel round() functions that I want to preserve, but other than that the formulae are pretty simple.
eg C1=round(A1*B1^2,0)
I want to change the formula in C1 to round (1*2^2,0)
Looking at the sheet, C1=4
I tried defining my range A1:AA1000, to extract the values (which would also iterate over a number of cells that contain formulae). I wanted to the iterate over the same range, find any formulae that contain cell references and replace those cell references with their values from the defined range.
There are also cells with text that I want to preserve, so I want to ignore the text or any excel functions and just look for cell references. Any ideas? code below but I am getting different errors, no formulae found, no cells found when I tinker with it.
Sub ReplaceCellReferencesWithValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim formulaCell As Range
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim formula As String
    Dim ref As Range
    Dim errorCell As String

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Define the range to search for values
    Set searchRange = ws.Range("A1:AA1000")  
    
    ' Check if there are cells with formulas in the specified range
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(searchRange) > 0 Then
        ' Loop through each cell in the specified range
        For Each cell In searchRange
            ' Check if the cell contains a formula
            If cell.HasFormula Then
                ' Get the formula of the cell
                formula = cell.Formula
                
                ' Loop through each cell reference in the formula
                For Each ref In cell.Precedents
                    ' Replace the cell reference in the formula with its value
                    formula = Replace(formula, ref.Address(False, False), ref.Value)
                Next ref
                
                ' Assign the updated formula back to the cell
                On Error Resume Next
                cell.Formula = formula
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    errorCell = cell.Address
                    Exit For
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub


What error do you get and which line? Scanning your code, your logic seems fine.

Thanks for your response -Method 'Formula' of object range failed

If you use local (non-English) version of Excel, use .FormulaLocal instead of .Formula. For example, if you use comma as decimal separator your ref.Value contains comma and .Formula expects decimal point.

You can try a simple change in your code. The below works on the few formulas you show, but without a more extensive data set, who knows:
Change:
cell.Formula = formula

to
                With cell
                    .NumberFormat = "@"
                    .Value = CStr(formula)
                End With

Also, here is a VBA function that may be helpful:

Use Regular Expressions to match any items in the formula that are cell references in the A1 style.
Replace the cell reference with it's value and output as a string
As written, it will cover the range of addresses in modern versions of Excel (A1:XFD1048576). If you are using earlier versions, you may want to modify it.
As written, it will only refer to cells on the same worksheet.

This is also a limitation of the Range.Precedents method you show in your code.
Could probably modify the code if this is an issue.



'Set Reference to Microsoft Vbscript Regular Expressions 5.5
'   (or could use late-binding
Option Explicit
Function ParseFormula(r As Range) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim sTempFormula As String
    
If Not r.HasFormula Then
    ParseFormula = ""
    Exit Function
End If
    
sFormula = r.Formula
sTempFormula = sFormula

'Get cell addresses
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "(?:\$?\b(?:XF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{1,2}))(?:\$?(?:1638[0-4]|163[0-7][0-9]|16[0-2][0-9]{2}|1[0-5][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-9]))\b"
    If .Test(sFormula) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sFormula)
        For Each M In MC
            sTempFormula = Replace(sTempFormula, M, Range(M))
        Next M
    End If
End With
    
ParseFormula = sTempFormula

End Function

